# To get Win Login info when Anon is turned on CFusion

Tags: iis, coldfusion, windows-authentication, anonymous

Basically, I'm trying to make a page which will display Login (eg #CGI.AUTH_USER#) if user is accessing the page Authenticated. However, if the user is non-Auth, I still want user to be able to access the page but with a login UI.

I currently have Anon Access ON and Windows Authen mode ON but looks like it doesn't work both ways.

If I have Anon Access ON, it does not retrieve the CGI.AUTH_USER.
If I have Windows Auth ON, it will prompt for user login when accessing the page.

Is there a way to make it so IIS accepts Anon users AND be able to retrieve user's Auth info if it is Windows Auth user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe this is possible, authentication under IIS is either on or off. If you turn it on you need to login before you see anything. If you turn it off you don't

Most people will just code up their own login page and authenticate this way. You can even use `<CFLDAP` to validate users against the active directory if you wish.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of this. I just wanted to be able to check if the user is authenticated and retrieve username if not, just proceed anyway. The whole reason why I want it like this is because when user accesses the website with Window Auth page (non-Anon) via WebVPN, SOME users are not able to load this page at all. They get one of those page you get when there is no network connection. That is the reason why I would like to also accept anon users.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it.  We turn it on for one CFM page and then we make a JavaScript call to that page.  Based upon the header response from that page we can see if the user is authenticated against an AD server that our IIS server recognizes.  If they are not authenticated off one then we present them with a login box so that they can "key" in their login information.

Comment: In your javascript approach, have you found a way to prevent the browser-based login prompt that normally appears when you hit a secured resource?  I've tried this exact approach (and many variations on it) and I was never able to stop the browser from displaying that annoying login prompt.

Comment: I honestly can't say that the login prompt ever comes up.  It might have something to do with how the corporate IT has configured the browsers within their standard images for machines.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that there is no way to stop the browser-based login prompt from appearing, short of some highly-tweaked underlying browser settings that you mention.  The problem with relying on those tweaks being there, however, is that it assumes the users with the tweaked browsers are the same users that would need the dialog suppressed - IE the non-trusted users.  However it is those very same non-trusted users that are the least likely to have their browsers tweaked (seeing as how they are probably off-domain).

Comment: Are you saying you always get prompted with the windows authentication box or it only happens if you are not part of the domain?  I have implemented the solution I mentioned on probably 1-2 dozen servers within our network and the windows authentication box to the best of my knowledge never shows up.  I know it does not show up for me or any of the users I have direct contact with.  I know the one time IIS on one server was messed up that the box did show and I got many complaints so would assume I'd be getting complaints today if it showed up on others.

Comment: I'm saying that if you try to request any resource (directly or indirectly) that requires Windows Authentication and your computer/browser is not part of the same trusted domain as the server is configured to accept, then the browser will prompt for login credentials.  It sounds to me like all of your users are part of the trusted domain, and in that case there is no reason to mix anon and win-auth - you could go with 100% windows auth.

Comment: We have our reasons for allowing SSO(via Windows authentication) and allowing non-SSO(keyed in login or screens that do not need authentication). The Windows Authentication system allows us to find out who the user is and then to look up what they have access to via that.  Some of our domains we cannot rely on the Windows Authentication string IIS gets and with those we force the user to do non-SSO.  I think a way to get around what you are running into would be using Flex/Flash.  We have a solution here that is similar to the JS one but is an embedded SWF(which makes the HTTP call).

Answer (score 0):

To address your specific technical question - you cannot have a single resource that allows both anonymous access and windows-based authentication.  However, you can have a main page that allows anonymous access, and a page in a sub folder that is secured with Windows Authentication, and both of those page can share the same CF application scope.  Using this basic arrangement is going to be required.

As to the base problem you're trying to solve, we've recently been spending some time on the feasibility of mixing the Windows Authentication approach with the existing web forms-based logins, just as you describe.  This is actually quite tricky, since the ideal situation would allow all users to access the same base URL they have always used, and auto-login silently and automatically when that option was available, but also to not be bothered with a browser-based login prompt when Windows Authentication is not available.  From what we've determined, that ideal isn't quite possible (due to some limitations in the HTTP protocol, a login prompt is always presented when accessing a secured resource).  However, we have found a few options that might be close enough to the ideal to be useful and worth pursuing:

1) You could have a special URL designated for users that would like to have this auto-login functionality; for example, something like https://baseUrl/autologin/ .  Domain users could bookmark that URL from machines that are on the domain, and use that bookmark to access the site.  If anyone other than a domain user on a domain computer went to that URL, it would prompt them to login with a browser-based login dialog.  Non-domain users would not be able to proceed from that dialog, but domain users would be able to.  All users (domain or not) could also login via the ordinary forms-based login screen that is normally available.  If you went with this option, you could also add a link on the homepage for users to "autologin" that would take them to this URL, which would of course only work for users on the domain.

2) You could try to identify certain network segments within your environment from which there is a very good chance that users requesting these websites will be doing so on a trusted domain computer.  You could structure the application in such a way so as to attempt to auto-login these users when they come from those identified networks.  In the case where there is a request from these networks which is not trusted, the worst thing that would happen is that the user would be unexpectedly presented with a browser-based username and password prompt.  If they did get that prompt, they could either ignore it by hitting cancel and proceeding to the ordinary login page, or they could enter their domain credentials and be logged in (in this case, it would likely be due to a desktop not being configured correctly for some reason - otherwise it would have auto-logged in).  This network-based detection method could be accomplished with the URL Rewrite module for IIS.

Comment: Thanks Jake. Basically I will paste what I wrote for Dale above. "Yes, I was afraid of this. I just wanted to be able to check if the user is authenticated and retrieve username if not, just proceed anyway. The whole reason why I want it like this is because when user accesses the website with Window Auth page (non-Anon) via WebVPN, SOME users are not able to load this page at all. They get one of those page you get when there is no network connection. That is the reason why I would like to also accept anon users."

Comment: Andding further comment to your alternate route, as I have inferred in my previous comment, all users who connect to this page are under same domain (VPNed in and all users are trusted). However, for some bizzare reason, it is OK for most people (either detects user's login auto OR prompts windows login, which is also fine) but for minority, they don't even get windows login popup box. They get the page you get when you have no internet connection. When they access pages with Anon enabled, it is fine.

Comment: You could verify that the users for whom it isn't working have added the site to their "trusted sites" configuration.  I've found that helps with auto-login, sometimes.